# My program keeps looping an inputbox. How do I get out of it?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a program that allows users to see information on songs, play an excerpt of them, and purchase selected ones.

And allow users to click the Purchase button to buy the indicated tune.

When checking out:

Users cannot checkout if they have not purchased any tunes, however they can exit the program.

Use an InputBox so that users can enter their sales tax rate. Since users are entering a value, you must perform data validation on their input.

Allow users to cancel the check out process by clicking the InputBox Cancel button.

When the input box is displayed, the textbox should have the focus, and when an incorrect tax value is added, the incorrect value should be cleared and the textbox should have focus again.

Use Write/Writeline to create a purchase order text file named PurchaseOrder.txt that includes the date the file was created and an itemized list of purchases, the subtotal, tax, and total.

When I click on the "Purchase" button of the selected song and click on the "Check Out" button, I get an inputbox, type the numeric value, however, it continues to loop over and over again. I don't get why this is happening. Please refer to the cmdCheckOut_Click subroutine in the code below. I think that's where I'm getting my error.

Here's the code:

```
   Public Structure musicInfo
    <VBFixedString(30)> Public title As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public artist As String
    <VBFixedString(20)> Public genre As String
    <VBFixedString(10)> Public duration As String
    Public year As Integer
    Public price As Double
    <VBFixedString(15)> Public songFileName As String
   End Structure

Public Const NoOfTunes = 5
Public songs(NoOfTunes - 1) As musicInfo


Option Explicit On
Imports System.IO
Public Class frmTunes
  Public index As Integer
  Public purchaseCount As Integer
  Public purchasePrice(10) As Decimal
  Public purchaseTitle(10) As String
  Dim decimal1 As Decimal
  Dim decimal3 As Decimal
  Dim decimal4 As Decimal
Private Sub frmTunes_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim i As Integer

    FileOpen(1, "music.dat", OpenMode.Random, , , Len(songs(0)))
    For i = 0 To NoOfTunes - 1
        FileGet(1, songs(i))
    Next
    FileClose(1)

    cmdPrevious.Visible = False

    DisplaySong(0)
End Sub

Sub DisplaySong(ByVal i As Int32)
    lblTitle.Text = songs(i).title
    lblArtist.Text = songs(i).artist
    lblGenre.Text = songs(i).genre
    lblDuration.Text = songs(i).duration
    lblYear.Text = Convert.ToString(songs(i).year)
    lblPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(songs(i).price)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdStop.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Stop()
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPurchase_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPurchase.Click
    purchaseTitle(purchaseCount) = lblTitle.Text
    purchasePrice(purchaseCount) = Convert.ToDecimal(lblPrice.Text)
    purchaseCount = (purchaseCount + 1)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPrevious_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPrevious.Click
    index = (index - 1)
    If (index < 4) Then
        cmdNext.Visible = True
    End If
    If (index = 0) Then
        cmdPrevious.Visible = False
    End If
    DisplaySong(index)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdNext.Click
    index = (index + 1)
    If (index = NoOfTunes - 1) Then
        cmdNext.Visible = False
    End If
    If (index > 0) Then
        cmdPrevious.Visible = True
    End If
    DisplaySong(index)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPlay.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(songs(index).songFileName)
End Sub

Private Sub cmdCheckOut_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdCheckOut.Click
    Dim str1 As String = ""
    If (purchaseCount = 0) Then
        MsgBox("You have not ordered any items!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Order Error")
    Else
        Do Until ((IsNumeric(str1) And (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) <= 10)) And (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) >= 0))
            str1 = InputBox("Enter your tax rate as a %" & vbCrLf & "between and including 0 - 10:", "Tax Rate", "", -1, -1)
            If (str1 <> "") Then
                If (Not IsNumeric(str1)) Then
                    MsgBox("You must enter a numeric tax rate", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
                Else
                    Dim decimal3 As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(str1)
                    If ((Decimal.Compare(decimal3, Decimal.Zero) < 0) Or (Decimal.Compare(decimal3, (10D)) > 0)) Then
                        MsgBox("You must enter a tax rate between and including 0% - 10%", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        Dim StreamWriter As StreamWriter = File.CreateText("PurchaseOrder.txt")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("For Purchases dated: " & DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString())
        StreamWriter.WriteLine()
        Dim num2 As Integer = (purchaseCount - 1)
        Dim num1 As Integer = 0
        Do While (num1 <= num2)
            StreamWriter.Write(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(Me.purchasePrice(num1), Decimal) & "     "))
            StreamWriter.WriteLine(purchaseTitle(num1))
            Dim decimal1 As Decimal = Decimal.Add(Nothing, purchasePrice(num1))
            num1 = (num1 + 1)

        Loop
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("------")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal1, Decimal)) & "  Subtotal")
        Dim decimal2 As Decimal = New Decimal(((Convert.ToDouble(decimal3) * 0.01) * Convert.ToDouble(decimal1)))
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal2, Decimal)) & "  Tax")
        StreamWriter.WriteLine("------")
        Dim decimal4 As Decimal = Decimal.Add(decimal1, decimal2)
        StreamWriter.WriteLine(Strings.FormatCurrency(CType(decimal4, Decimal)) & "  Total")
        MsgBox("Purchase Order has been created", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        StreamWriter.Close()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: use a breakpoint on the DO UNTIL statement, then use the immediate window or the mouse to evaluate those conditions, 1 (or more) is not what you think it is.  Also no need to `Dim decimal3 As Decimal` over and over -  it is declared as a module var at the top.

Comment: What's a breakpoint? Show me the code for that.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktf38f66(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Can you give me something else that's easier to understand? I don't see the significance in using this breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it looks like you're using Decimal.Compare wrong.,  See if this helps:

```
    Do 
        str1 = InputBox("Enter your tax rate as a %" & vbCrLf & "between and including 0 - 10:", "Tax Rate", "", -1, -1)
        If (str1 <> "") Then
            If (Not IsNumeric(str1)) Then
                MsgBox("You must enter a numeric tax rate", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
            Else
                Dim decimal3 As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(str1)
                If decimal3 < 0 Orelse decimal3 > 10 Then
                    MsgBox("You must enter a tax rate between and including 0% - 10%", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Tax Rate Error")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until (IsNumeric(str1) Andalso (decimal3 <= 10 Andlso decimal3 >= 0))
```

Comment: But now the Subtotal, Tax and Total values do not appear.

Comment: Still didn't appear. This is so frustrating!

Comment: Then you have a different problem that was being masked by the loop not exiting.  This will make sure that decimal3 has a proper value.  I notice that you're multiplying it with decimal1 to get decimal2.  If decimal1 and/or decimal3 is 0 decimal2 will be 0 as well.

Comment: Also instead of writing everything to a file right away, consider using a multiline textbox and use the appendtext method to display the data.  Once you get the program displaying the data the way you want, now change it to write to the file.  You'll find this quite a bit less frustrating.